# What is the best way of reducing the number of independent variables of a GLMM?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, feature-selection, aic, glmm

I am trying to model the abundance of beach litter across different beaches by using (currently) 13 independent variables. I have a very big dataset and therefore think that it is acceptable to use quite a lot of ind variables but I know that some of them are correlated to some degree. However, I do think that choosing between either one of the two correlated variables might reduce the power of the model, as it makes sense that both might have an effect on the dependent from a biological point of view. Finally I just wanted to point out that the sampling was not done by me but by volunteers and therefore the data is both biased and datapoints are not really independent (which is why I'm using a GLMM).

I am considering either using PCA but I feel that having 2000+ sample points would make this very hard, otherwise I have tried to do perform a stepwise regression with AIC as the criterion but have read in another post that this is usually not the best way of going about it.

Comment: you can try the PCA, see how much of the variance can be explained by the PCs.. and take it from there

Comment: Hello - your choice of tags shows that you recognize the applicability of the term "feature-selection" - there is a wealth of information on this, on this site and elsewhere.  Instead of asking for general advice on what is ultimately a general problem, can you narrow down your question based on any of the information currently available?

Comment: Thanks @rolando2, I have to admit that I found the term while researching other questions on this site and have now seen that the term is mostly used in machine learning, which is a subject that I do not have much knwoledge of.

Comment: Sorry I accidentally cut the comment @ rolando. My question came about more because performing correlation tests between some of the independent variables of my model I have seen that a lot of them are correlated. Reading other posts, and considering that I have very little knoweldge of ridge selection, do you think that PCA would be a good way of performing the selection of the variables?

Comment: I'm not being flip when I say this:  whether PCA or stepwise regression or something else would be good depends on a great many things, including your criteria for what would constitute "good."  This sounds like a pretty open-ended situation suited for a consultant or coach rather than for a one-shot answer on a web page.